# How to track user statistic in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, usage-statistics, user-data

I'm looking for a solution to get some information about the amount of bypassed premium purchases.

My actual approach in short: I keep track of the usage when a premium feature is -used- and send this data to my web server.

Actually my concept provides that the user grants "read account information" permission. So I am able to receive the **Android-ID** and the **Gmail-Account** as well. At the end I hope to get some useful information about security issues, which maybe hide in my In-App-Billing code, by comparing the information in my wallet with the database.

My question:

- I am not sure if it is really necessary to collect these user data at all. As some of you know, here in Germany people get in panic fast, when somebody wants to collect usage information.

I appreciate any helpful information. Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need the user information to provide statistics? Generate some random semi-unique id and sent it like that.

Comment: Yes, sounds good. I will give it a try. Thanks for this simple, but clever idea.